# Скрипт по изменению размера изображения

Tags: jquery, php

Как написать скрипт, который бы обрабатывал картинку, если она, например, большого разрешения, а на выходе нужно, чтобы она была примерно 150 на 150 пикселей?

Answer (score 3):

ниже функция, если мало - [сюда](http://subcoder.ru/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE/) пожалуйста  )

```
/***********************************************************************************

 Функция img_resize(): генерация thumbnails
    Параметры:
      $src             - имя исходного файла
      $dest            - имя генерируемого файла
      $width, $height  - ширина и высота генерируемого изображения, в пикселях
    Необязательные параметры:
      $rgb             - цвет фона, по умолчанию - белый
      $quality         - качество генерируемого JPEG, по умолчанию - максимальное (100)
    ***********************************************************************************/

function img_resize($src, $dest, $width, $height, $rgb=0xffffff, $quality=100)
{

  if (!file_exists($src)) return false;

  $size = getimagesize($src);

  if ($size === false) return false;

  // Определяем исходный формат по MIME-информации, предоставленной
  // функцией getimagesize, и выбираем соответствующую формату
  // imagecreatefrom-функцию.
  $format = strtolower(substr($size['mime'], strpos($size['mime'], '/')+1));
  $icfunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;
  if (!function_exists($icfunc)) return false;

  $x_ratio = $width / $size[0];
  $y_ratio = $height / $size[1];

  $ratio       = min($x_ratio, $y_ratio);
  $use_x_ratio = ($x_ratio == $ratio);

  $new_width   = $use_x_ratio  ? $width  : floor($size[0] * $ratio);
  $new_height  = !$use_x_ratio ? $height : floor($size[1] * $ratio);
  $new_left    = $use_x_ratio  ? 0 : floor(($width - $new_width) / 2);
  $new_top     = !$use_x_ratio ? 0 : floor(($height - $new_height) / 2);

  $isrc = $icfunc($src);
  $idest = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

  imagefill($idest, 0, 0, $rgb);
  imagecopyresampled($idest, $isrc, $new_left, $new_top, 0, 0, 
    $new_width, $new_height, $size[0], $size[1]);

  imagejpeg($idest, $dest, $quality);

  imagedestroy($isrc);
  imagedestroy($idest);

  return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Максим Кузнецов РНР5 на примерах." Я по ней занимался. Там есть все ответы на вопросы.
Было бы желание вникать. Там и про вывод сжатого изображение в браузер без сохранения в отдельный файл.))

Comment: Хмммм, а возможен вариант без того, чтобы измененная картинка помещалась в отдельную папку?

Comment: А просто изменялся размер оригинала?

Comment: Можно, но нагрузка сильно возрастет, ведь при большом количестве посетителейсервер

Comment: Вероятно придется делать асинхронное сжатие, добавляем в очередь на сжатие организованную, например, в БД и какой-то демон в несколько потоков будет этим заниматься. В случае если этим будет заниматься демон легче будет регулировать степень его влияния (нагрузки) на сервер, понижая или повышая его приоритет.

Comment: Только вопрос: а нафига, если можно просто закешировать? =)

Answer (score 1):

Вконтакт реализует интересный механизм, если для загрузки был выбран flash-загрузчик, то пережимкой фоток занимается он, а дальше он уже отправляет их на сервера-хранилища. Надо сказать весьма неплохой способ снять нагрузку с серверов :)

Answer (score 0):

А не проще обрабатывать изображения при загрузке? Пользователь загружает изображение, скажем 1280х1024, вы его в 150х120 пропорционально складываете в папочку, например, не image, а image/thumbnail/, а при генерации страницы уже берёте ужатую копию, формируя, скажем, ссылку на полное изображение.